# How to add calculated column to Dataframe counting frequency in column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, countif

I have dataframe like this:

```
   county
1     N
2     N
3     C
4     N
5     S
6     N
7     N
```

and what I'd like to reach is:

```
    county  frequency
1   N       5
2   N       5
3   C       1
4   N       5
5   S       1
6   N       5
7   N       5
```

Is there any possibility to add such column directly without any intermediate df. I know that I could create another df with group and size function and merge this two dataframes. Howewer, I wonder if there is any function which enable such solution without any intermediate df but maybe with usage of 'apply' and some function or lamba?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by without requiring an intermediate `DataFrame`, but seems like you want `.transform`: `df['freq'] = df.groupby('county').county.transform('size')`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Map the values from value_counts to the column

```
df['frequency'] = df['county'].map(df['county'].value_counts())

    county  frequency
1   N       5
2   N       5
3   C       1
4   N       5
5   S       1
6   N       5
7   N       5
```

Comment: This worked but caused the following message: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: @AlmogWoldenberg, The column on which you used map would have been created by copying from another column rather using loc. If you show the code on how your df was generated, I can help troubleshoot